# Unable to bind Application item - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have created 2 application items in shared component option.

- Protection level: Restricted
- Scope: Application

Then I have created a process in the login page where sql query is

```
select user_id, name into :G_USER_ID , :G_USER_NAME
from t_users
where upper(email) = upper(:P9999_USERNAME);
```

When I try to login it gives me error. Debugging says that there is an error in the above statement. I am not able to bind these items.

I'm using apex 19.1

Comment: Don't create processes in a login page. Instead create an application process with processing point after authentication, that is much more transparent and a much better practice.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you said *which* error you got.

However, if this piece of code runs **before** you managed to log in, you didn't establish connection to the database (yet) and can't select from any table, including `t_users`.

Comment: Error statement: then this whole query is written.

Comment: The process is of after successful login.

Comment: Okay I figured it out. Thanks anyways :)